# How to construct particular De Bruijn sequences

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, computer-science

For $n \ge 2$, there is at least one binary DeBruijn sequence beginning with $n$ zeros followed by $n$ ones.  Is there a straightforward way to construct such a sequence for each $n \ge 2$?  Examples:

$n=2: 0011$

$n=3: 00011101$

$n=4: 0000111101100101$

$n=5: 00000111110111001101011000101001$

Comment: What's the proof that there is at least one such sequence for all $n\geq 2$?

Comment: the proof are the lexically minimal De Bruijn sequences constructed as described [here](http://royvanrijn.com/blog/2011/02/generating-de-bruijn-sequences-and-lyndon-words). In the lexical ordering a maximal contiguous sequence of $0$-bits is adjacent to maximal sequence of $1$-bits after making the sequence cyclic. Cutting the cyclic sequence in the right place and adjusting the direction gives the sought sequences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is the construction of the De Bruijn sequence by concatenating certain Lyndon words as indicated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyndon_word) or, in this [article](http://emoreno.uai.cl/publicaciones/PREPRINTS/preprint-WORDS03-Lyndon_words_and_de_Bruijn_sequences_in_a_subshift_of_finite_type.pdf); that construction also guarantees the existence of the specific De Bruijn sequences you are looking for.

A very comprehensible hands on explanation of the construction can found [here](http://royvanrijn.com/blog/2011/02/generating-de-bruijn-sequences-and-lyndon-words).

Answer (score 7):

One of the simple ways to generate De Bruijn sequenceis the following rule. You write $n$ zeros, and after that "$1$ is better than $0$" (left hand rule):
$$0000111101100101000$$
For example 9th digit is $0$ because we already have $1111$. This algorithm was taken from the article [N. M. Korobov, "Concerning some questions of uniform distribution"](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=im&paperid=3266&option_lang=eng). In the article [Normal periodic systems and their applications to the estimation of sums of fractional parts](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=im&paperid=3296&option_lang=eng) he proposed a more general algorithm which allows to generate all possible De Bruijn sequenceis.