# Optimal Encoding of Sets with DeBruijn-likeSequences

Tags: algorithms, sequences-and-series, coding-theory

A [DeBruijn sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence) of order $n$ encodes *all* possible strings of length $n$ over an alphabet with $k$ symbols and algorithms for their construction are well known among those familiar with the subject; see for example [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/235080/how-to-construct-particular-de-bruijn-sequences).

> **Question:**
>
> Given a fixed collection of sets of length $n$ strings over an alphabet with $k$ symbols:
>
> - (when) is it possible to find a (minimal) set of additional length $n$ strings that, when added (possibly with repetitions) to the given collection of sets, allows it to encode each set in a DeBruijn-like manner, i.e. in each of the generated (cyclic) sequences $n$ adjacent symbols either resemble an element of the encoded set or an element of the additional set?
> - provided the existence of such sequences: is it possible to construct them to optimality, i.e.,  either minimizing the maximal length of the set-encoding strings or minizing their summed lengths.

Remark:
In the encoding of the sets uniqueness of the elements is not required; especially if non-uniqueness allows more compact overall encoding of the sets.